# ForEach How to close out button effect when another button is toggled

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that generates multiple rows in a list. Each row - I append a button that creates a pop out of sorts over the row. My issue is since the button is being generated separately on each row, when I toggle another button on a different row, the previous button I opened remains open until I click it again.

Is there a way I can have the rows communicate with each other so if another button is clicked, the button previously clicked disappears?

```
struct RecipeFullListRow: View {
   var body: some View {
                    ZStack{
                        Text("Cheese Omelette")
                            .font(.body)
                  
                        Text("10g 25g 88g")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.top, 80)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                            .frame(height:90)
                        
                        if showRecipeOptions{
                            ReditorPopUp(shown: $showRecipeOptions)
                                    .padding(.top, 20)
                                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                        }
                    }
                        .padding(.top, -10)
                        .padding(5)
                    
                   
                    Button(action: {
                      
                        
                    }){
                        Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .onTapGesture{
                                showRecipeOptions.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                   
   
     
    }
}
```

**BUTTON ATTACHED TO EACH ROW

```
struct ReditorPopUp: View {
    @Binding var shown: Bool
    @State var showEditRecipe = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if shown{
            ZStack{
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 20){
                    HStack(spacing:12){
                        Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            .font(.title2)
                        Button(action:{
                            showEditRecipe.toggle()
                               
                        }){
                            Text("Edit")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        } .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                        //present editor
                            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showEditRecipe){
                                    RecipeEditor()
                                }
                    }
                    HStack(spacing: 12){
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }){
                            Text("Delete")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        } .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.white)
            ///art of animation
            .transition(.backslide)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25))
        }
        
    }
}

struct RecipeFullListView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var listofRecipes: [RecipeListModel] = RecipeList.recipes
    @State private var active = false
  
   
    
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let withIndex = listofRecipes.enumerated().map({ $0 })
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Recipes")
                    //.padding(.bottom, -20)
                    //.padding(.top, 40)
                    .font(.title2)
               
                List{
                    ForEach(withIndex, id: \.element.name){ index, recipe in
                        RecipeFullListRow(recipe: recipe, recipeName: recipe.name, index: index)
                    }
                }
              
            }//end of VStack
        }
        
    }

}
```

I have also attached a gif of the issue below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Bool make it `index` or row `item` type, so when button clicked instead of `toggle` assign current row/item, this will close previous automatically before show current. Of course you need to inject into the view index/item from ForEach level.

1)

```
    if showRecipeOptions == index {  // index of current row, ...
//    if showRecipeOptions == item { // or item of current row
        ReditorPopUp(shown: $showRecipeOptions)
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .padding(.leading, 15)
    }
```

2. ```
     Button(action:{
         showEditRecipe = index    // index of tapped row
   //        showEditRecipe = index  // or item of tapped row

     }){
   ```

**Update:** simplified demo for idea (tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5) - each row has own index (or unique item) and externally provided selection (either via binding or via view model in environment object).

[image: demo]

```
@State private var active: Int? = nil   // external single choice
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Row(active: $active, index: $0) // << inject both
        }
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    @Binding var active: Int?
    let index: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Item \(index)")
                .onTapGesture { active = index }  // I'm activated
            Spacer()

            // if I is activated show something...
            if index == active {
                Button("Done") { active = nil } // if needed to clean
            }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: active)
    }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestSingleRowActivation.swift)

Comment: Thanks for this, I added a forEach on my list, but since the button is on a different view, having trouble understanding what to do after my index is passed to the button's view

Comment: If button in different view then you should pass binding to `showRecipeOptions` in it, so `index` refers to button, and `showRecipeOptions` refers to selection.

Answer (score 0):

In your data model (`ObservableObject`) holding data for each row, you could add a variable holding the index of the row being selected for editing with `@Published` wrapper. Changing it would redraw the list with the edit view for new row.